# Is there some Javascript caveat I'm missing? Scope issues?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, mongoose

I've wrote a JavaScript object, that scrapes a list of websites using the standard nodeJS http get method.

It was quite tricky (for me: a relative nube to JS) to handle all of the asynchronicity, and queue the requests one by one, so that my machine didn't fire off thousands (about 2500) requests at once and obviously crash.

So here is the idea, and how it currently works:

```
var scraper = new WebsiteScraper();
mongooseDocs.forEach(function(doc){ 

    var callback = function(outputFromWebPage, done){

        var email = /*try find email*/

        if(email){
            doc.email = email;
            doc.save(function(){
                done();
            })
        }else{
            done();
        }

    }
    scraper.scrape(doc.website, callback);
})






function WebsiteScraper() {

    this.active = true;
    this.queue = [];

    /** Add url to queue */
    this.scrape = (function (url, callback) {
        //console.log(url);
        this.queue.push({url: url, callback: callback});
    }).bind(this);

    /** Execute the scrape */
    this.execute = (function (url, done) {



        if(url.indexOf("http") === -1) done();

        var protocol = /https/.test(url) !== false ? https : http;



        var req = protocol.get(url, (function (response) {

            var output = '';

            console.log("request made");

            response.on('error', function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                done(false);
            })
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                output += chunk;
            })
            response.on('end', (function () {
                console.log("Request complete", url);
                done(output);

            }).bind(this))
        }).bind(this));

        req.setTimeout(20000, function () {
            console.log("Timed out");
            done(false);
        });

        req.on('error', function (e) {
            console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
            done(false);
        })

        req.end();


    }).bind(this);

    this.check = (function () {

        if (this.queue[0] && this.queue[0].callback) {

            this.execute(this.queue[0].url, (function (output) {
                this.queue[0].callback(output, (function(){
                    this.queue.shift();
                    this.check();
                }).bind(this));
                console.log(this.queue.length, ' left in queue');
            }).bind(this));

        }
        else {
            setTimeout(this.check, 100);
        }


    }).bind(this);

    this.check();


}
```

Essentially: loop through records and add them to the list. The website scraper internally goes through the list and executes the requests so long as there are urls in the queue. When the request is finished it executes the user defined callback, and only on done() does it execute the next request.

It works fine, it finds the emails but when it moves on the next record if it doesn't find an email address it saves the previous outputs email. I've tried various different bindings and deleting the email variable after its done.

This has been bugging me for about a month now, PLEASE HELP :D

Comment: Um, `scraper.scrape(urlToScrape, callback);` is not inside the `forEach` body???

Comment: My bad. It is in my actual code. Will edit

Comment: May I recommend you use [async.eachLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) to handle most of the asynchronicity for you? I mean, it's great that you tried yourself! That's how you learn stuff.:) But for serious work, I recommend it.

Comment: Hey yeah, thanks :) i've used that for now, but i wanted to be able to dynamically add links to the end of the queue should I find one on the page I find relevant. I know I can do this in async as well i guess but not in one long dynamic queue. Unless I'm wrong, which I very well could be :) I was hoping to learn something by being able to do it this way @RobertRossmann